# Populate a vtkDataSet(vtkStructuredGrid) with data stored in a vtkDataArray?

Tags: c++, vtk

Im using structured and unstructured grids.
I have a 3D grid, like this.
[image: 3D grid using structured grid]
I want each cell to have a vector of attributes.

So, if i have a **vtkDataArray** (vtkDenseArray for example). For each cell:

### How could i populate the vtkStructuredGrid with those data stored in the dataArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python I would do this:

```
import vtk,math

sg = vtk.vtkStructuredGrid()

n = 6
sg.SetDimensions([n,n,n])

vec = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
vec.SetNumberOfComponents(3)

pts = vtk.vtkPoints()

for kx in range(n):
    for ky in range(n):
        for kz in range(n):
            pts.InsertNextPoint(kx*0.1,ky*0.1,kz*0.1)
for kx in range(n-1):
    for ky in range(n-1):
        for kz in range(n-1):
            vec.InsertNextTuple([math.cos(ky*0.05*math.pi),
                                 math.sin(kx*0.05*math.pi),0.1*kz])

sg.SetPoints(pts)
sg.GetCellData().SetVectors(vec)

w = vtk.vtkXMLStructuredGridWriter()
w.SetInputData(sg)
w.SetFileName('sgrid_cd.vts')
w.Write()
```

I don't think the use of vtkDenseArray in c++ should make it any different.